# Export Graph SAIKU REST API

Tags: api, rest, svg, saiku

I would like to export created ThinQuery as graph(Pie, Line...) by calling this API route, but don't know what to send for "svg" param.

Please, help me with one "svg" param example.

```
/**
 * Export PDF with chart
 * @summary Export PDF with Chart.
 * @param queryName The query.
 * @param svg The SVG string
 * @return A response with a PDF file
 */
@POST
@Produces({"application/pdf" })
@Path("/{queryname}/export/pdf")
public Response exportPdfWithChart(
        @PathParam("queryname")  String queryName,
        @PathParam("svg")  @DefaultValue("") String svg)
{
    return exportPdfWithChartAndFormat(queryName, null, svg, null);
}
```